# Connecting Maschine to Synth

Tags: midi, midi-controller-keyboard

I have a Yamaha MO8 and have just purchased Maschine (Native instruments)

Can I set it up so that I can play the synth and have the sounds from Maschine play and record?

I know I can purchase the Complete Controller, but was hoping I could achieve what I want with what I already have.

Comment: You might find this tutorial helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P2zFEHyBoZU

Comment: Or this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JkDKV9ys3z8

Comment: Thanks for the links, they helped me a bit but I am still having some troubled. 

If I connect midi cables out of the back of the synth, into the mac, I get sound, however if I use the USB cable out of the back of it, I get nothing, no sound. would prefer USB to work. 

Using the midi cables for input, I put on a piano sound and played it, I started using the foot switch which is connected to my synth for sustain, but it will play fine for a while, then out of no where, a loud random note will play, and at the same time, the sustain is lost until I lift up and put down my foot again.

Comment: The first link is a USB tutorial, it didn't work for you? Are you using Maschine as a plug-in inside a DAW or as stand-alone? The loud random note could be a hardware issue, try to test that setup with another keyboard and pedal and the keyboard by itself without connecting it to maschine.

Comment: Hi, as a standalone, I have logic , but I find that for what I am doing the maschine 2 app is lighter so seems better that way. The keyboard on its own does not have that issue. I hooked up a second synth to the mac (via midi cable) and the same random note issue occurred but was actually worse, as it was happening even just playing without a  sustain pedal. I wondered if the keyboard is sending out too much midi data and its getting overrun? or maybe the midi-usb cable isn't a good one? Just updated the maschine software to 2.2.3 , will try it again and see if the latest update helps

Comment: well it lasted longer before it went haywire, but its still not right,

Answer (score 1):

**Without a DAW**

Connect MIDI-out port of Yamaha MO8 to MIDI-in port of Maschine with a MIDI cable. This way you can directly trigger Maschine sounds from Yamaha O8. Maschine will playback the MIDI channel picked on Yamaha O8.

```
    [Yamaha MO8] MIDI-out >---> MIDI-in [Maschine] USB --- USB [PC] >---> Audio OUT
```

**With your DAW**

The other way is to use your DAW for the routing.

- Connect your both devices' MIDI or USB ports to your computer.
- Create an empty MIDI channel on your DAW.
- Set Yamaha MO8 to MIDI-In of the Maschine plug-in instrument of that channel.

  In some DAW's you can directly send Yamaha MO8 to the plug-in instrument as MIDI-in.
- If necessary, adjust MIDI channel numbers for ins and outs.

For the stand alone version, most stand alone synths have an option for that but it may be different for Maschine's case because of NI's marketing strategy. In this case you can always use the first option above (Without a DAW).

I think connecting Yamaha MO8 to Maschine hardware directly with MIDI cable is a better solution becasue you can use both hardware for input directly without any extra work. Doing that within the DAW may need extra work and complicated routing. Actually it depends on what will you do with them.

Comment: Maschine doesn't have a line out, or any type of audio output, it is a control surface. The recording is done through Maschine's software (stand-alone or plug-in), DAW, or an audio interface (depends on what you want to record, audio, MIDI, or both). Also you don't need MIDI cables, you can use USB and connect the devices through the PC (which would make more sense than using MIDI through the PC when you can just connect them directly).

Comment: @JCPedroza Thanks a lot for the notice. I totally missed that part and edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have finally got this working.

The MO8 had its midi setting set to "midi" which made sense, but it should have been set to "USB" , which does beg the question of why it showed up on the mac at all?

Once I change that, maschine started working correctly without the random notes.